# How to register dll in sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss

How can register the dll in the sharepoint. There is any tool or command available?. please provide the details like source location

Answer (score 2):

The only good way to deploy assembly to SharePoint is to use SharePoint Solution. So the assembly will be deployed to all servers in your farm.

If you're using SharePoint 2007: http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx

If you're using SharePoint 2010, use Visual Studio 2010 with (included) SharePoint extensions.

To get started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint

Comment: That's rather vague - for SP 2010.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add this to gac

Example

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\V2.0\Bin\gacutil.exe /i  "C:\MyPath\MyDll.dll"
```