# How do I register Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL file?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dll, ssis, regsvr32

I am developing C# (VS 2008) code in a SSIS Task (SQL Server 2008 R2) script that will automatically check in (using SPFile method) newly created Excel files into a SharePoint site after they are copied to the appropriate UNC path.  Since I am developing on a computer that does not have SharePoint installed, I need to copy to my computer and register the Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL file (version 2010) in order to reference and apply its associated methods.

The problem I am having is that I am unable to register the Micrsooft.SharePoint.DLL file on my computer using Windows 7 and was hoping that somebody can assist.

Here is what I've done so far and with the following results:

1. Copied Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL to folder C:\Windows\System32 and verified that the file is present.
2. Verified that regsvr32.exe is located in folder C:\Windows\System32.
3. Ran the following command in C:\Windows\System32 with the following result:
    regsvr32 Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL

   Box pops up with following message:
    'The module "microsoft.sharepoint.dll" was loaded but the entry-point  DllRegisterServer was not found.  Make sure that "microsoft.sharepoint.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.'

The DLL file was provided by the SharePoint administrator.

I have also rebooted my computer, as recommended on some other IT sites, but that has made no difference.

Until I can register the Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL file, I cannot apply it as a reference in my code.  Can somebody assist?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to register dll in sharepoint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441373/how-to-register-dll-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Side note - it may be useful to read about differences between COM dll and .Net Assemblies.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No it's not a duplicate of that question. The OP is trying to achieve something else — remote development.

Comment: You should use **[CSOM or JSOM to can build a SharePoint solution without the need to have a SharePoint Installed](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/create-sharepoint-windows-forms-application/)**

Answer (score 2):

That is impossible by design. Developing and/or running SharePoint-related code on a machine where SharePoint isn't installed is not supported and there is no workaround.

In case you *must* do it like that and you target SharePoint 2010, consider using [client object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535231.aspx).

Comment: Upon further testing, I was able to successfully register the Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL file using the GACUtility. The trick was to first register all three of the following in folder C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\SharePoint: Microsoft.SharePoint.dll, Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll, and microsoft.sharepoint.WorkflowActions.dll.  After this was done, I then returend to Visual Studio, selected the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll file as a reference.  This time, it remained listed as a reference after saving and closing and then reopening.

Comment: However, this is practically useless: you can't run the code, you can't debug the code. It's just wasted effort. SharePoint development does have to occur on a server box with SharePoint installed. (Having it installed on a Win 7 machine is also possible, but unnecessary pain again.)